# How adjust code that works only if I move the mouse

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

My code should be right, however it works only if I move my mouse, even if I didn't even set up one.
the code should draw concentric circles moving.

I have even tried by blocking the mouse, but it still doesn't work

```
import pygame
import math
import time
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
black = (0,0,0)
keep_going = True

white = (255,255,255)
freq = 10
num_circles = 0
radius = 0

while keep_going:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keep_going = False


        radius = radius + 1
        num_circles = math.ceil(radius / freq)
        screen.fill(white)

        radiusMax = num_circles * freq

        pace = freq / radiusMax


        for y in range(num_circles, 1, -1):

            radiusY = int(((pace * (num_circles - y)) + pace) * radiusMax) + (radius % freq)

            pygame.draw.circle(screen, black,(400, 300), radiusY, 1)

        pygame.display.update()           
pygame.quit()
```

I would like to know why the hell I get this kind of bug, how to solve it, and if it's not possible, a possible solution.

Comment: I'd suggest making the habit of writing all your code in English. This will allow people who don't speak your language to understand your variable, and hence code, better. Also, most production code is in English, so it's a good habit to have if you would ever pursue a career in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused, because you do all the code in the event loop. The code in the event loop is executed only, when an event occurs, such as mouse movement (`pygame.MOUSEMOTION`).

Do the drawing in the main loop rather than the event loop, to solve the issue:

```py
while keep_going:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keep_going = False

    #<--
    #<--
    #while input() != "quit":
    #for x in range(1): #importante
    raggio = raggio + 1
    num_cerchi = math.ceil(raggio / freq)
    screen.fill(white)

    raggioMax = num_cerchi * freq

    passo = freq / raggioMax
    #time.sleep(5)

    for y in range(num_cerchi, 1, -1):
    # 1, -1

        raggioY = int(((passo * (num_cerchi - y)) + passo) * raggioMax) + (raggio % freq)

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black,(400, 300), raggioY, 1)

        #raggio = raggio+1 #importante
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()           
pygame.quit()
```